Define a grid to fit the available height of the page
I apologize if this question has already been asked.
How to define the hauteur in the following code so that the grid fits dynamically the available height of the page? Thank you very much!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % This is the package for random text

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\def\width{\dimexpr0.95\textwidth\relax}
\def\hauteur{13} % Height of the grid

\begin{document}

% Generate some random text before the grid
\lipsum[1]  % Generate the first paragraph of random text

% Create a tikz picture with grid
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
        % Draw grids with different steps and line widths
        \draw[step=1mm, line width=0.1mm, black!30!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!40!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
        \draw[step=5cm, line width=0.5mm, black!50!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
        \draw[step=1cm, line width=0.3mm, black!90!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\hauteur);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}


The tikzpagenodes package defines, similar to the current page node, a current page text area node. By positioning the TikZ picture at the very left side of the page area, we can use the current page text area.south east position to fill the remaining space.
Instead of letting TikZ figure out the size of the picture (which would make this a bit annoying to deal with when less space becomes available), I'll use overlay (which means the picture has no size) and use \newpage to instruct LaTeX to end the current page.
The remember picture key is always needed when dealing with these page nodes.
Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % This is the package for random text

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcommand*\tikzgrid{%
  \par\noindent\tikz[
    remember picture, overlay, baseline=-1ex,
    Step/1mm/.style={line width=.1mm, draw=black!30},
    Step/5mm/.style={line width=.2mm, draw=black!40},
    Step/1cm/.style={line width=.3mm, draw=black!90},
    Step/5cm/.style={line width=.5mm, draw=black!50}]
  \foreach \step in {1mm, 5mm, 5cm, 1cm}
    \draw[Step/\step, step=\step] (0,0) grid (current page text area.south east);%
  \newpage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\tikzgrid

\lipsum[1]
\tikzgrid
\end{document}


My first attempt with l3box (interface3 documentation).
Code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % This is the package for random text

\usepackage[margin=1in,
showframe%<-- added, comment in the final document
]{geometry}

\def\width{\dimexpr0.95\textwidth\relax}
% \def\hauteur{13} % Height of the grid
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_Dimitrios_box
\dim_new:N \l_Dimitrios_ht_dim
\dim_new:N \l_Dimitrios_dispo_dim

\NewDocumentCommand{\mybox}{ +m }
  {
    \vbox_set:Nn \l_Dimitrios_box { #1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_Dimitrios_ht_dim {\box_ht:N \l_Dimitrios_box}
    \dim_set:Nn \l_Dimitrios_dispo_dim {\dim_eval:n {\textheight-\l_Dimitrios_ht_dim-\baselineskip}}
    \box_use:N \l_Dimitrios_box
    %%%%%  for latex2
    \cs_new_eq:NN \hauteur \l_Dimitrios_dispo_dim
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mybox{\lipsum[1]}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
        % Draw grids with different steps and line widths
        \draw[step=1mm, line width=0.1mm, black!30!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\the\hauteur);
        \draw[step=5mm, line width=0.2mm, black!40!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\the\hauteur);
        \draw[step=5cm, line width=0.5mm, black!50!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\the\hauteur);
        \draw[step=1cm, line width=0.3mm, black!90!white] (0,0) grid (\width,\the\hauteur);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}



Only works if there is nothing before \mybox
